# Need Some Guidance on Setting Up or Structuring my Test Plan with a combination of Grovy sample, Mq Broker and jmeter

Tags: jmeter

All, i would like to get some advice and assistance in structuring my Testplan to achieve my goal see below for my test script outline.

1. I have a MQ WebSphere server hosting locally.
2. I have an Endpoint that will receive an http Request and Provide a response.

I want to monitor the time taken for the request and response.

In order to Get the request from the Queue i had to use the JSR223 sampler
In this sample i am consuming the message from the Queue and i am reading that message extracting the message and write it to a variable  messageText. I wanted to use this variable and use it in my http request Thread. An article mentioned to use csv data set config. I tried using this Http controller to get the message and I am unable to get it. The request failed.

The Second Problem i am facing is that the jsr223 group consumer thread is running and then after it finishes its iteration its then running the http request.

1. I want to be able to Have a controller that will control the request user and iteration and for each iteration it will get the message from the queue then post that request to the end point and get back the message and log the time. Every user should do that.
2. I also want to know when running this performance test i will need to run this in batch mode right? what the strategy there?
3. One main thing is that my authentication where i add it once only controller, my token expires every 2 hours... for each request for each user, i am assuming i need to treat them as real user that has not authenticated to use the endpoint and would need to authenticate and then send the request... Trying to understand how i should set this part up as well?

[image]
[image]

Code as follows:

```
 import com.ibm.mq.*
 def strQueueManagerName = "QM2"
def strChannelName = "CHANNEL1"
def strQueueName = "QUEUE1"
 def strServerName = "127.0.0.1"
def intPort = 1414

MQEnvironment.hostname = strServerName
MQEnvironment.channel = strChannelName
MQEnvironment.port = intPort
MQEnvironment.properties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES

 try {
def mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(strQueueManagerName)

// Define a Queue
def queue = mqQueueManager.accessQueue(
    strQueueName,
    MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
)

def getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
def retrievedMessage = new MQMessage()

// Read a message from the queue
queue.get(retrievedMessage, getOptions)

// Process the retrieved message
def messageBytes = new byte[retrievedMessage.messageLength]
retrievedMessage.readFully(messageBytes)

def messageText = new String(messageBytes, "UTF-8")  // Assuming the message is 
 encoded in UTF-8

// Log the message
log.info("Received message: " + messageText)

// Save the messageText to a variable
vars.put("messageTextVariable", messageText)

// Mark the message as removed from the queue
retrievedMessage.messageFlags = MQC.MQMF_NONE
retrievedMessage.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE
queue.put(retrievedMessage)

queue.close()
mqQueueManager.disconnect()
} catch (Exception ex) {
log.error(ex.message)
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `vars.put("messageTextVariable", messageText)` to `props.put("messageTextVariable", messageText)` in your [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which reads the message from the queue.
2. Change `${messageTextVariable}` in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(messageTextVariable,)}`

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)